KMPlayer in Wine plays Quicktime video distorted (codec ID is: mp42)
I installed KMPlayer (https://www.kmplayer.com/home) in Wine and got it running almost fine.
But there are some videos that give a distorted image when played, and some others get muted halfway (but the image is fine). Looking at their configurations, I found differences with videos that play correctly.
The distorted video has this codec ID: mp42 (mp42/isom) and the format profile is: Base Media / Version 2. As far as I understand, the video cannot play correctly mp4 version 2 files, right?
Also, the distorted video cannot play at all in native Ubuntu players, like the default one or SMPlayer.
I'm currently running Ubuntu 24.04 and I cannot find a straightforward solution to this issue. Can you suggest anything to solve this?
For example, this video from YouTube gets muted halfway when played with KMPlayer in Wine. Its Codec ID is: isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
https://youtu.be/JdZ_XsyHqc4
I'm listing the technical information of the distorted video so you may see something relevant:
General
Format                         : MPEG-4
Format profile                 : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                       : mp42 (mp42/isom)
File size                      : 73.1 MiB
Duration                       : 3 min 14 s
Overall bit rate mode          : Variable
Overall bit rate               : 3 150 kb/s
Frame rate                     : 29.970 FPS
Movie name                     : Hernán Darío y Los Muchachos Decentes • Aquí Está El Bobo
Genre                          : Guasca, Popular
Encoded date                   : 2024-11-10 22:03:27 UTC
Tagged date                    : 2024-11-10 22:05:36 UTC

Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AVC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Video Codec
Codec ID                       : avc1
Codec ID/Info                  : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                       : 3 min 14 s
Bit rate                       : 3 017 kb/s
Width                          : 1 422 pixels
Height                         : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 4:3
Frame rate mode                : Variable
Frame rate                     : 29.970 (29970/1000) FPS
Minimum frame rate             : 29.004 FPS
Maximum frame rate             : 29.970 FPS
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.066
Stream size                    : 70.0 MiB (96%)
Encoded date                   : 2024-11-10 22:03:27 UTC
Tagged date                    : 2024-11-10 22:05:36 UTC
Codec configuration box        : avcC

Audio
ID                             : 2
Format                         : AAC LC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                       : mp4a-40-2
Duration                       : 3 min 14 s
Duration_FirstFrame            : 67 ms
Bit rate mode                  : Variable
Bit rate                       : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                     : 2 channels
Channel layout                 : L R
Sampling rate                  : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                     : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode               : Lossy
Stream size                    : 2.97 MiB (4%)
Title                          : Stereo
Encoded date                   : 2024-11-10 22:03:27 UTC
Tagged date                    : 2024-11-10 22:05:36 UTC

[Lista de Filtros]
  (1) Built-in MP4 Source
  (2) Built-in Video Codec/Transform
  (3) Enhanced Video Renderer(Custom Present)
  (4) Built-in Audio Codec/Transform
  (5) DirectSound Audio Renderer

[Información vídeo]
  Códec: AVC1 - Interno FFmpeg(h264, Thread Frame)
  Entrada: AVC1(24 bits)
  Tamaño entrada: 1422 × 1080(1.32:1)
  Tipo salida: YUY2(16 bits)
  Tamaño salida: 1422 × 1080(1.32:1)
  Cuadros/seg: 29.969
  BitRate: Desconocido

[Información audio]
  Códec: AAC(0xaac0) - Interno FFmpeg(aac)
  Frecuencia: 44100 -> 44100 muestras/seg
  Bits por muestra: 16 -> 16 bits/muestra
  Canales: 2 -> 2 canales
  Bitrate: 0 kbps

And the info for the muted video is:
General
Format                         : MPEG-4
Format profile                 : Base Media
Codec ID                       : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                      : 81.3 MiB
Duration                       : 4 min 1 s
Overall bit rate               : 2 828 kb/s
Frame rate                     : 60.000 FPS
Movie name                     : El Cuarteto de Nos • Ya no sé qué hacer Conmigo (Letra)
Performer                      : FredoDeNos
Genre                          : Rock en Español
Recorded date                  : 2021
Writing application            : Lavf58.39.101
Comment                        : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raZhGlUFi-A

Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AVC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                 : High@L4.2
Format settings                : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC         : Yes
Format settings, Reference fra : 3 frames
Codec ID                       : avc1
Codec ID/Info                  : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                       : 4 min 1 s
Bit rate                       : 2 691 kb/s
Width                          : 1 348 pixels
Height                         : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 5:4
Frame rate mode                : Constant
Frame rate                     : 60.000 FPS
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Scan type                      : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.031
Stream size                    : 77.3 MiB (95%)
Title                          : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
Color range                    : Limited
Color primaries                : BT.709
Transfer characteristics       : BT.709
Matrix coefficients            : BT.709
Codec configuration box        : avcC

Audio
ID                             : 2
Format                         : AAC LC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                       : mp4a-40-2
Duration                       : 4 min 1 s
Bit rate mode                  : Constant
Bit rate                       : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                     : 2 channels
Channel layout                 : L R
Sampling rate                  : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                     : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode               : Lossy
Stream size                    : 3.68 MiB (5%)
Title                          : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
Language                       : English
Default                        : Yes
Alternate group                : 1

[Lista de Filtros]
  (1) Built-in MP4 Source
  (2) Built-in Video Codec/Transform
  (3) Enhanced Video Renderer(Custom Present)
  (4) Built-in Audio Codec/Transform
  (5) DirectSound Audio Renderer

[Información vídeo]
  Códec: AVC1 - Interno FFmpeg(h264, Thread Frame)
  Entrada: AVC1(24 bits)
  Tamaño entrada: 1348 × 1080(1.25:1)
  Tipo salida: YUY2(16 bits)
  Tamaño salida: 1348 × 1080(1.25:1)
  Cuadros/seg: 60
  BitRate: Desconocido

[Información audio]
  Códec: AAC(0xaac0) - Interno FFmpeg(aac)
  Frecuencia: 44100 -> 44100 muestras/seg
  Bits por muestra: 16 -> 16 bits/muestra
  Canales: 2 -> 2 canales
  Bitrate: 128 kbps


Are you able to place one of the difficult files online? Seems odd that Linux media players cannot come to grips with the files as usually these sort of players use FFmpeg libraries...

For example, this video from YouTube gets muted halfway when played with KMPlayer in Wine. Its Codec ID is: isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
https://youtu.be/JdZ_XsyHqc4

I found an answer for my mp41 audio problem with KMPlayer playing within Wine:
Turns out that all I needed was to change this configuration in Preferences:
Press F2
Expand (click on +): Connection of Filters (of Filter Connection)
Select: Splitter
Click on the option: MP4, MOV, and select: KMP MP4/MOV Splitter (By default it was the Built-in option. The system default option wont work either)
That's it.
Saludos
